# Android Studio: dynamically created button layout is cropped

Tags: android, dialog, trim

I have problem with my app and I cannot find any rational explanation why is this happening. I create dynamically Dialog Box:

```
final Dialog dialog = new Dialog(content);
dialog.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
dialog.setCancelable(false);
dialog.setCanceledOnTouchOutside(false);
dialog.getWindow().setLayout(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT);
LinearLayout popUp = getProperLayout(s1,content);
popUp = generateFinalLayout(s,popUp,content);
// Button
LinearLayout btnLayout = new LinearLayout(content);
btnLayout.setOrientation(LinearLayout.HORIZONTAL);
btnLayout.setGravity(Gravity.RIGHT);
btnLayout.setPadding(8,0,8,12);
Button cancel = new  Button(content);
cancel.setText("OK");
cancel.setBackgroundColor(Color.TRANSPARENT);
cancel.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#0078ff"));
cancel.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            dialog.cancel();
        }
    });
btnLayout.addView(cancel);
//Dodaj
popUp.addView(btnLayout);
dialog.setContentView(popUp);
```

getProperLayout:

```
public static LinearLayout getProperLayout(String s1,Context content) {
    LinearLayout properLayout;
    properLayout = new LinearLayout(content);
    properLayout.setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL);
    properLayout.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#EEEEEE"));
    properLayout.setPadding(16,16,16,16);
    LinearLayout.LayoutParams params = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT);
    properLayout.setLayoutParams(params);
    // Treść informacji
    TextView nameText = new TextView(content);
    nameText.setText(s1);
    nameText.setPadding(16, 36, 16, 36);
    nameText.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER_HORIZONTAL);
    //Dodaj wszycho
    properLayout.addView(nameText);
    return properLayout;
}
```

generateFinalLayout:

```
public static LinearLayout generateFinalLayout(String title,LinearLayout popUp,Context content) {
    LinearLayout properLayout;
    properLayout = new LinearLayout(content);
    properLayout.setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL);
    properLayout.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#EEEEEE"));
    LinearLayout.LayoutParams params = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
    properLayout.setLayoutParams(params);
    //  Tytuł
    TextView titleTv = new TextView(content);
    titleTv.setText(title);
    titleTv.setTextSize(20f);
    titleTv.setTextColor(Color.WHITE);
    titleTv.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#0056BB"));//29394E"));
    titleTv.setTypeface(null, Typeface.BOLD);
    titleTv.setPadding(16, 16, 16, 16);
    // Poszerzacz
    TextView extender = new TextView(content);
    extender.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#2278DD"));//Color.parseColor("#18283d"));
    params = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(712,0);
    extender.setLayoutParams(params);
    extender.setPadding(2, 22, 2, 22);
    // Poszerzacz2
    TextView extender2 = new TextView(content);
    extender2.setBackgroundColor(Color.TRANSPARENT);//Color.parseColor("#18283d"));
    params = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(712,4);
    extender2.setLayoutParams(params);
    extender2.setPadding(2, 22, 2, 22);
    // Dodajparams
    properLayout.setPadding(0,0,0,0);
    properLayout.addView(titleTv);
    properLayout.addView(extender);
    properLayout.addView(popUp);
    properLayout.addView(extender2);
    return properLayout;
}
```

And on many devices (S3, LG V490, S5,S7) it looks ok. But on client's HTC it looks like this:
[image][image]

Any idea, why is this happening?
Removing padding doesn't solve anything...

Comment: Dialog is created dynamically and there is no xml, but I forgot to put generateFinaLayout code. Editing.

Comment: Please let me know the use of two methods in below lines 

LinearLayout popUp = getProperLayout(s1,content);
popUp = generateFinalLayout(s,popUp,content);

means getProperLayout and generateFinalLayout

Comment: There You go, I added them in question. Sorry for confusion.

Comment: One line missing .. add that dialog.show(); else working correct.

i add in a new answer check that

Comment: Try to reduce paddings of button's layout or one of its parent.

Comment: Dialog show is added in code, this is just method that creates dialog. I do not understand what You mean about "else"? Reducing paddings is a good idea...

Answer (score 0):

```
final Dialog dialog = new Dialog(MainActivity.this);
            dialog.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
            dialog.setCancelable(false);
            dialog.setCanceledOnTouchOutside(false);
            dialog.getWindow().setLayout(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT);
            LinearLayout popUp = getProperLayout("Proper",MainActivity.this);
            popUp = generateFinalLayout("Final",popUp,MainActivity.this);
            // Button
            LinearLayout btnLayout = new LinearLayout(MainActivity.this);
            btnLayout.setOrientation(LinearLayout.HORIZONTAL);
            btnLayout.setGravity(Gravity.RIGHT);
            btnLayout.setPadding(8,0,8,12);
            Button cancel = new  Button(MainActivity.this);
            cancel.setText("OK");
            cancel.setBackgroundColor(Color.TRANSPARENT);
            cancel.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#0078ff"));
            cancel.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View view) {
                    dialog.cancel();
                }
            });
            btnLayout.addView(cancel);
            //Dodaj
            popUp.addView(btnLayout);
            dialog.setContentView(popUp);
            dialog.show();
```

else is same

Comment: A few words of explanation what you changed and why would be really great!